# NoReverseMatch Error Django

Tags: python, django, reverse, django-urls

I have the following model:

```
class UserPlaceReview(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(PlaceReview)
    review = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review

class PlaceReview(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image     = models.ImageField(upload_to = image_upload_location,null=True, blank=True)
    category  = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    slug =      models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("categories:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

In my main urls.py I have the following url:

```
url(r'^categories/', include('places.urls', namespace='categories')),
```

and in my app urls.py I have the following url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/review/$', user_place_review, name='user_review'),
```

In a template I am trying to do something like this which gives me a no reverse match error:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'categories:user_review' %}">Write A Review!</a>
```

The view linked to the url is :

```
def user_place_review(request,slug):
    place = PlaceReview.objects.get(slug=slug)

    form = UserPlaceReviewForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        review = form.cleaned_data['review']
        instance.place = place
        instance.review = review
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/')




    context = {
    "form": form,
    }



    return render(request,"places/user_review.html", context)
```

I am unable to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'categories:user_review' %}">Write A Review!</a>
```

to

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'categories:user_review' slug=placereview_instance.slug %}">Write A Review!</a>
```

Where placereview_instance is your model object.You defined URL of `user_review` with slug keyword argument in the `urls.py` file. So Django is looking for keyword argument slug in that url in the template.It can not find the same, so it is throwing No reverse match found.

Also as you already defined `get_absolute_url` in `models.py`.In the same way you can directly use another method for review and then use in the templates ,

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ placereview_instance.get_review_absolute_url }}">Write A Review!</a>
```

Comment: The instance.get_absolute_url does not work as I have (slug)/review added in my url. It will keep me on the same page and wont take me to /review

Comment: Thanks a lot. The other option in which we pass the slug from our instance works

Comment: ok, create one more method for absolute url of review and it will work also

Answer (score 0):

You must give a value to the args of the url. your template should look like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'categories:user_review' slug='your_parameter' %}">Write A Review!</a>
```

.